# d3 draw horizontal bipartite graph for word alignment visualization

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am trying to write a script to generate the following visualization from a word alignment file (for this it will contain 1-1 1-2 2-5 3-3 etc.),
[image]

I found [this](http://bl.ocks.org/NPashaP/9796212), but do not know how to make this a horizontal bipartite graph instead of vertical. I am new to d3, so any pointers on how to accomplish this will be great.

Comment: Take the exact file you linked to and make it horizontal. That's literally the easiest way I can think of reproducing that graph horizontally.

Comment: i think it would be best to visualize this vertically...the main reason being that you can have a vertical scroll when the data is too large

Comment: The issue with vertical scroll is that I may have very long sentences, and then it becomes tedious. With horizontal scroll, I can wrap text into a paragraph and then show alignments between them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have created a sample visualization with D3; might be helpful to your purpose: 
https://github.com/danyaljj/sentenceToSentenceAlignmentVisualization

```html
<!DOCTYPE html><html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.js"></script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/4.1.1/d3.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <p style="text-align: center;">
        <svg width="95%" height="200">
            <rect x="0" y="0" width="100%" height="160" stroke="#000000" stroke-width="2" fill="#EFFFFF" ></rect>
            <text x="10" y="23" stroke-width="1" stroke="#000000" font-family="sans-serif" font-size="15" > Text: </text>
            <text id="svg-text" x="50" y="23" font-family="sans-serif" font-size="15" >  </text>
            <text x="10" y="140" stroke-width="1" stroke="#000000" font-family="sans-serif" font-size="15" > Hypothesis: </text>
            <text id="svg-hyp" x="100" y="140" font-family="sans-serif" font-size="15" >  </text>
        </svg>
        </p>
        <script>
            function highlightEntities(entities, blockID, yCoordinate) {
                entities.forEach(function(item, i) {
                    var offset = document.getElementById(blockID).getStartPositionOfChar(Number(item[1][0])).x;
                    var width = document.getElementById(blockID).getStartPositionOfChar(Number(item[1][1])).x - offset;
                    d3.select("svg").append("rect").attr("x", offset).
                                                    attr("y", yCoordinate).
                                                    attr("width", width).
                                                    attr("height", 28).
                                                    attr("fill", "yellow").
                                                    attr("opacity", 0.3).attr("stroke-width", 0.5).attr("stroke", "red");
                });
            }
            var text = "Ed O'Kelley was the man who shot the man who shot Jesse James.";
            var hyp = "Ed O'Kelley was a good man.";
            var textY = 0;
            var hypY = 10;
            d3.select("#svg-text").text(text);
            d3.select("#svg-hyp").text(hyp);
            var textEntities = [
                ['T1', [0, 11]],
                ['T2', [20, 23]],
                ['T3', [37, 40]],
            ];
            var hypEntities = [
                ['H1', [0, 11]],
                ['H2', [18, 22]],
                ['H3', [23, 26]],
            ];
            highlightEntities(textEntities, "svg-text", 5);
            highlightEntities(hypEntities, "svg-hyp", 122);
            // create a map from entity to entity-id
            var entityToIdMap = {};
            function addEntityToMap(entities) {
                Array.from(entities).forEach(function (item) {
                    console.log(item);
                    if (entityToIdMap[item[0]] == null) {
                        entityToIdMap[item[0]] = item[1];
                    }
                    else {
                        console.error("ERROR: repetition of entity IDs! Potentially duplicate information! ");
                    }
                });
            }
            addEntityToMap(textEntities);
            addEntityToMap(hypEntities);
            var relations = [
                ['R1', 'T2', 'H1'],
                ['R2', 'T1', 'H2'],
                ['R3', 'T3', 'H3'],
            ];
            // this function defines the curve of the edges
            function positionLink(x1, y1, x2, y2) {
                return "M" + x1 + "," + y1
                        + "S" + (x1+x2)/2 + "," + (y1+y2)/2
                        + " " + x2 + "," + y2;
            }
            // get x-y coordinates for edge start-eneds
            var yOffset = 9;
            relations.forEach(function(item){
                var entity1Loc = entityToIdMap[item[1]];
                var entity2Loc = entityToIdMap[item[2]];
                var blockID = 'svg-text';
                var x1 = (document.getElementById(blockID).getStartPositionOfChar(Number(entity1Loc[0])).x +
                        document.getElementById(blockID).getStartPositionOfChar(Number(entity1Loc[1])).x) / 2;
                var y1 = document.getElementById(blockID).getStartPositionOfChar(Number(entity1Loc[0])).y + yOffset;
                blockID = 'svg-hyp';
                var x2 = (document.getElementById(blockID).getStartPositionOfChar(Number(entity2Loc[0])).x +
                        document.getElementById(blockID).getStartPositionOfChar(Number(entity2Loc[1])).x) / 2;
                var y2 = document.getElementById(blockID).getStartPositionOfChar(Number(entity2Loc[0])).y - yOffset -8;
                d3.select("svg").append("path").attr("d", positionLink(x1, y1, x2, y2)).
                                                attr("stroke", "red").
                                                attr("stroke-width", "2");
            });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Here is a screenshot:
[image]